# iBeacon app not detecting location of beacon properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, beacon

I'm developing ibeacon receiver app.  It is not using location properly i guess and it is not detecting the beacon... I've already seen lot of solution but nothing works thats why am asking again...

Here is my code

```
self.uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:myuuid];
self.major = 1;
self.minor = 1;
self.region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:self.uuid major:1 minor:1 identifier:@"com.appcoda.testregion"];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

I downloaded an app from http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/ to act as beacon

Comment: Your question is not clear, which one you need use location ?

Comment: For detecting the beacon I've used CLLocation.  In settings I've set the location to always

Comment: For receiver app @Arasuvel

Comment: @SivagamiSundari Which beacons are you using Estimote?

Comment: am using iBeacons

Comment: Do you know your transmitter is working?   Can you see the beacon with an off the shelf derectorcapp like Locate?  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8

Comment: I checked the app which is acting as beacon with the sample app available from https://www.raywenderlich.com/66584/ios7-ibeacons-tutorial it is working

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks the monitoring and ranging methods. You need to create region in which you want to detect the beacon.

```
let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: item.uuid,
                                            major: item.majorValue,
                                            minor: item.minorValue,
                                       identifier: item.name)
```

And then you need to start monitoring for the region and you will get the beacons in the delegate of ranging method.

```
  let beaconRegion = beaconRegion
  locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
  locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
```

Comment: @SivagamiSundari Have you implemented the delegate methods?

Comment: yes.  didEnterRegion, didExitRegion and didRangeBeacons I've added that is enough right?

Comment: did you set the location manager delegate to self? And make sure your Bluetooth is on in the device and not in airplane mode.

Comment: yeah I've set it properly

Comment: Am trying to update the label text when detecting the beacon. But the delegate methods are not get called

Comment: @SivagamiSundari Need to check the code then. Are you using virtual beacon?